# Convert Divs into accordion upon resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 divs next to each other in the desktop view. However, upon resizing to ~640px, these divs should condense into an accordion.

Any ideas or tips on how to accomplish this?

Example >

**(On desktop)**

|  DIV#1  |  DIV#2  |  DIV#3  |  DIV#4  |

**(On mobile, at 640px)**
–––––––––––
Accordion   +
–––––––––––
DIV#1
DIV#2
DIV#3
DIV#4
–––––––––––

Comment: show us what u have tried??

Comment: @Shashank I don't know where to begin. I'm used to html CSS and no JS experience

Comment: If no js experience how r u gonna understand the solution??
take up js tutorials...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css media query alongwith js:

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">+</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="a">B</div>
<div class="a">C</div>
<div class="a">D</div>
<div class="a">E</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {
    /* Styles */
    div {
        display:block;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #544454;
        margin:5px
    }
    .a {
        display:none;
    }
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-width : 641px) {
    /* Styles */
    .accordion {
        display:none;
    }
    .a {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:10px;
        width:80px;
        height:40px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion').on('click', function () {
        $('.a').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/335/

Re-size the window to see the effects. Adjust the media query value according to your needs

Comment: Ah! I see so you're conditionally triggering the appearance of the accordion by visibility. and then appending the elements under it. Great solution! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah. The code is pretty much self explanatory and easy. You can refer media query for more details.

Comment: hey K K, had a quick question. In the accordion JS you described, the animation of the accordion seems to be scaling up from the top and the left. Is there a way to apply a "slide" animation so that it animates / scales only vertically in one direction. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B4T2K/

Comment: @user3886632 Yes it can be done. Instead of using .toggle('fast'), use .slideToggle('fast') in the code. Updated the code. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

try this. listn to window resizing, if height goes below 640, write the jquery/JS code to convert it to accordion.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
                if(window.innerHeight < 640)
                    //change it to accordion here
            });
```